# going back to previous commit without destroying the current one

Tags: git

So I wanted to go back to my previous commit without destryoing the latest one I have now. How do I do this? Doing a git reset HARD will destroy my current commit right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [GIT revert to previous commit... how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/git-revert-to-previous-commit-how)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you don't have any changes that you have not checked in, `git checkout $OLD_COMMIT` will take you there, and `git checkout $BRANCH` will take you back.

That will put you, potentially, on a detached head; see `git checkout --help` for the details, but if all you want is to run tests on the old version or something that should be fine.

You might also be interested in:
`git stash` - to store away uncommitted changes temporarily
`git show $SHA1` to show the changes of the old commit as a diff
`git show ${REF}:${PATH}` to show the content of $PATH in $REF

(Ref can be a sha, or a branch, or whatever, in the last git show invocation.)

Comment: Just for any newbs: when he says "git checkout $OLD_COMMIT" he typically might mean "git checkout b46b" (start of the SHA).  There's no dash or dollar sign or anything.  Going back to the main branch you would do something like "git checkout master", if "master" is the name of the branch.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`git revert`](http://book.git-scm.com/4_undoing_in_git_-_reset,_checkout_and_revert.html). This allows you to undo a specific commit without upsetting commits since.

If I understand your case correctly, you have:

```
* abc123de a_good_commit
* bc123def a_bad_commit
* c123def4 another_good_commit
```

You can either `git revert HEAD^` or use a specific hash: `git revert bc123def`.

Answer (score 0):

Doing any kind of `reset` to a previous commit will remove your later *commits* from your branch such that they're no longer part of it.  A *commit* being the items you see when you do `git log`.

This doesn't mean those commits are instantly destroyed, but as your intention isn't to get rid of them, you'd probably want to create another branch and use that to look at your previous commit so that your original branch is left with the latest commits intact.  (Keywords for creating a new branch are: `git branch <name>` or `git checkout -b <name>`. **)

Hard vs soft reset has more to do with what happens to the files in your working tree, and more importantly to uncommited changes.  In essense, the only things destroyed when you specify `--hard` are your uncommited changes.  As long as you've left a branch at your latest commit (or you remember the commit id), you can always recover the files by switching back to that branch or commit. (i.e. `git checkout`)

** You can actually look around without creating an extra branch and Daniel Pittman's answer describes that.